# Printing all table items to console

Tags: javascript, html, console.log

There's a bunch of table items on a website that I want to pull into the console, and preferable space with a tab...

How do I do this?
They are literally embedded with the tag `<i></i>` which I've not seen before.

```
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('table')[5].items[0].toString)
```

It's in the 5th table, I've got that bit right, but no idea on how to get the items

Comment: too bad this hasn't been implemented yet .. but it's been thought of: https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#table

Comment: Ever tried XPath?

Comment: Did any of the answers solve your problem? If so, please mark that answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You're currently logging a method, `toString`, rather than the result of its invocation (`toString()` - note brackets).

Next, if I understand right that you want to log the contents of all the `i` tags in the selected table, you need to retrieve them and iterate over them:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('table')[5].querySelectorAll('i').forEach(i => {
    console.log(i.textContent);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty method would be to just grab the `innerText` attribute of the table you wish to log.

```js
//substitute [0] for the table you want.
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")[0].innerText)
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Value</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><i>1</i></td>
      <td><i>Cake</i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><i>2</i></td>
      <td><i>Banana</i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><i>3</i></td>
      <td><i>Apple</i></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to loop through the contents of the table and log it like so. Another way is to construct an object and log that object:

```js
const items = document.getElementById('table').getElementsByTagName("li");

function printOneByOne() {
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    console.log(items[i].textContent);
  }
}

function printObject() {
  const values = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    values.push(items[i].textContent);
  }
  console.log(values);
}

function printOneLine() {
  let value = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    value += items[i].textContent + "\t";
  }
  console.log(value);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="printOneByOne()">Print one by one</button>
<button onclick="printObject()">Print object</button>
<button onclick="printOneLine()">Space with tab</button>
<ul id="table">
  <li>First value</li>
  <li>Second value</li>
  <li>Third value</li>
  <li>Fourth value</li>
</ul>
```